# xammpp error (i have this error while installing Xampp and apache. how do i handle it?)

Tags: php

```
XAMPP Installation Directory: "e:\xampp\"
Checking for prerequisites
All prerequisites found
Initializing Modules
***
```

> Problem detected!     Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with
>   PID 4!    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!    You
>   need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application    or
>   reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
>     XAMPP Apache Service is already running on port 443

---

```
XAMPP MySQL Service is already running on port 3306
***
```

> Problem detected!     Port 8080 in use by
>   ""E:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice"!      Tomcat WILL NOT
>   start without the configured ports free!      You need to
>   uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application    or reconfigure
>   Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

---

```
Starting Check-Timer
Control Panel Ready
Executing "services.msc"
Attempting to stop Apache service...
Attempting to stop MySQL service...
Status change detected: stopped
Status change detected: stopped
```

Comment: You will find lots of answers about why these ports are typically already in use on MS-Windows systems without the knowledge of the users. Just use google.

Comment: If you run skype, kill it. Use `processmon.exe` to check, what is holding your ports.

Answer (score -2):

I disabled bluetooth and all other running connections and applications,and it worked fine for me